# Sequelize.Model does not exist

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use the Class syntax for Sequelize when importing models but I get this error. It appears that `Model` isn't in that `sequelize` object.

Code:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends sequelize.Model {}
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

If I do the `define` method it works fine

```
sequelize.define('users', {}, {sequelize})
```

I'm importing it simply like it says in the docs;

```
const UserModel = db.import(__dirname + "/src/models/user");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your class file you must import the model directory:

`const UserModel = require('directory/../models/users');`

`class SampleRepository {
 constructor(model) {
 super(model);
 }`

`module.exports = new SampleRepository(UserModel);`